# spring security core grails not logging in

Tags: grails, spring-security

Installed Spring Security Core as plugin then did quickstart

Here is my User domain class

```
package auth
class User {
   def springSecurityService
   String username
   String password
   boolean enabled
   boolean accountExpired
   boolean accountLocked
   boolean passwordExpired
   static mapping = {
          // password is a keyword in some sql dialects, so quote with backticks
          // password is stored as 44-char base64 hashed value
       password column: '`password`', length: 64
   }
   static constraints = {
       username blank: false, size: 1..50, unique: true
       password blank: false, size: 8..100
   }


   Set getAuthorities() {
      UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
   }

   def beforeInsert() {
     encodePassword()
   }

   def beforeUpdate() {
      if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
      }
   }

   protected encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, username)
   }
}
```

And my boostrap.groovy is

```
class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->

    auth.User james = new auth.User(username: 'test', enabled: true, password: 'password')
    james.save()
    if (james.hasErrors())
    {
        println("he has errors")
    }


    println("we made it! ")
}

   def destroy = {
   }
}
```

But when I go to login, it keeps saying "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password."  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the [salt](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/12%20Password%20and%20Account%20Protection.html#12.2%20Salted%20Passwords) while encoding the password.

```
password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, username)
```

I have no idea of salting and hence can not guide you to much.

But if you encode your password without salting then your code works, **just remove username when encoding the password**, try this

```
password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the user in `BootStrap.groovy`, try changing this:

```
def adminUser = User.findByUsername('admin') ?: new User(
    username: 'admin',
    password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin'),
    enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
```

to this:

```
def adminUser = User.findByUsername('admin') ?: new User(
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
```

The problem is that you are using the encoding password twice, once in the Domain and once in the constructor's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate that the user is actually bootstrapped into the database?

If so, I ran into a similar issue with Tomcat caching some data incorrectly.

Here is what I did:

1. Stopped Tomcat
2. Deleted all the files in Tomcat's Temp directory
3. Restarted Tomcat

After that, it worked fine.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: So I am using intellij and using the tomcat plugin.  Also using an in memory database.  Would this just involve removing and adding the tomcat plugin?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  But, another person asked a similar question and said cleaning the project helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985126/grails-2-3-0-view-rendering-issue/18985225#18985225

Answer (score 0):

Also, its been a while since I've built a Grails site from scratch, but I think I remember there being an issue with some online instructions.  SpringSecurity might be encoding the password for you, so when you do it, it is getting ***double encoded***.

> Try removing the lines that encode the password.

Comment: Tried this, got the same result :(